# How to charge a phone without it turning on?

Tags: charging, sony-xperia

I've got Sony Xperia Z2 (phone) and Sony Xperia Z1 (tablet). Every time I put one of them on charging (and pick up from charging for that matter), the device will turn on. I don't like it and I'd prefer it to stay turned off.

How can I cause that?

Comment: Does it boot straight to Android or just to some charging animation? If it boots straight to Android, your phone may not support *offline charging*. Usually your phone needs to make sure that the battery is charged safely (prevent overcharging or overheating), so there has to be some software running.

Comment: In the scenario I'm talking about, it's not really booting per se. The device is turned on since before and then put on charge. After a while, it turns off (goes to sleepy-sleepy-mode or whatever it's called). When I pick it up and disconnect the charging cable, the screen comes to live. I want to be able to pick it up without it coming alive.

Comment: Have you turned on Day Dream in Settings > Display?

Comment: @MANI It was turned off. When I turn it on, it asks what the device is supposed to do but i see no option for "stay dark" or whatever it might be called.